# Formatting an exception in python to include all but the last 'n' traceback frames

Tags: python, exception, traceback

Assume you had a setup like this:

```
def a():
    b()

def b():
    c()

def c():
    d()

def d():
    e()
```

Attempting to call `a()` would result in the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#181>", line 1, in <module>
    a()
  File "<pyshell#87>", line 2, in a
    b()
  File "<pyshell#90>", line 2, in b
    c()
  File "<pyshell#93>", line 2, in c
    d()
  File "<pyshell#96>", line 2, in d
    e()
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

Is there any way to format the exception so that it only includes the last `n` frames in the traceback? For example, if `n = 2`, the traceback would look like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#93>", line 2, in c
    d()
  File "<pyshell#96>", line 2, in d
    e()
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

I've tinkered with it for a little bit and can't figure out a way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from Python 3.5, functions from the [*traceback* module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/traceback.html) support negative limits (the original proposal was inspired by your question and approved by Guido):

```
import traceback

n = 2

try:
    a()
except:
    traceback.print_exc(limit=-n) # `n` last traceback entries
```

outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vaultah/test.py", line 8, in c
    d()
  File "/home/vaultah/test.py", line 11, in d
    e()
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

You can replicate this behavior even if you use older Python

```
import sys, traceback

n = 2

try:
    a()
except:
    ex = traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())
    sys.stderr.write(''.join([ex[0]] + ex[-n-1:]))
    # or print(*[ex[0]] + ex[-n-1:], sep='', end='', file=sys.stderr)
```

The output will be exactly the same.

Comment: you can do `print(''.join(ex[1:-1][:-n-1:-1]))` instead of `for` loop

Comment: The only problem with this is that when I do it it doesn't include the 3rd and fifth lines (where it includes the code written in `d` and `c` that caused the errors). Why might it be doing this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well. The traceback included in your answer is 

``Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/frost/test.py", line 10, in c
    d()
  File "/home/frost/test.py", line 13, in d
    e()
NameError: name 'e' is not defined``

whereas the one I'm getting is only

``Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/frost/test.py", line 10, in c
  File "/home/frost/test.py", line 13, in d
NameError: name 'e' is not defined``. (The formatting in comments is terrible, you might want to copy it into a text editor or something to see it better).

Comment: @user3002473 from [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_tb): *if the source is not available it is None*. Seems like interpreter doesn't provide the source for some reason. I get the correct results when I run this code from file.

Answer (score 0):

The [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module has many functions that you should help you achieve what you are looking for. 
Specially, the limit options of many of these function

```
import traceback
def d():
    c()

def c():
    b()

def b():
    a()

def a():
    print traceback.extract_stack(limit=1)      

d()
```

Will return a tuple representing the last **a** call

Comment: Is there no way of using this to get a traceback that only included `b` and `a` in this case? This is the same as what I had above but the names are reversed.